# Wheel turning but vehicle not moving

Tags: vocabulary

What is this action called in English?
"Wheel turning but car not moving forward, like when there is sand under the wheel and it is difficult for the vehicle to move forward".

Also, what do you call this action in English when we change the gear to a lower gear in manual-gear vehicles so that the vehicle moves with more power and less speed, like when you're traveling an uphill road and the vehicle is losing its speed. Then you change the gear from gear 4 to 3.

Comment: Do you mean *spinning/slipping* and *downshifting*?

Comment: Or _changing down_ for the latter in British English.

Comment: It is also used as a metaphorical phrase as in " I can't get anything done; I'm just spinning my wheels over here."